# Core data bulk insert suddenly slows to 1/10th the speed

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-data

I am bulk inserting into core data. I have a person object, and this person object has a relationship called "otherPeople" that is an NSSet of people. When bulk inserting data from a download, things were great until about 10,000 people are read in at which point the bulk insert speed slows down to a crawl. I am saving and resetting my NSManagedObjectContext every 500 inserts.

If I comment out the part that inserts the "otherPerson" relationships, the bulk insert is speedy through the entire download. parseJSON is called in batches of 500 JSONKit dictionaries.

Any ideas what might be causing this? Possible solutions?

Code:

```
- (NSArray*) getPeople:(NSArray*)ids
{
    NSFetchRequest* request = [[[NSFetchRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
    NSEntityDescription* entityDescription = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Person" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    [request setEntity:entityDescription];
    [request setFetchBatchSize:ids.count];

    //Filter by array of ids
    NSPredicate* predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"externalId IN %@", ids];
    [request setPredicate:predicate];

    NSError* _error;
    NSArray* people = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&_error];

    return people;
}

- (void) parseJSON:(NSArray*)people
{
    NSAutoreleasePool* pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    NSMutableArray* idsToFetch = [NSMutableSet setWithCapacity:CHUNK_SIZE * 3];
    NSMutableDictionary* existingPeople = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithCapacity:CHUNK_SIZE * 3];

    // populate the existing people dictionary first, that way we know who is already in the context without having to do a fetch for each person in the array (externalId IS indexed)
    for (NSDictionary* personDictionary in people)
    {
        // uses JSON kit to parse out all the external ids...
        [PersonJSON addExternalIdsToArray:idsToFetch fromDictionary:personDictionary];
    }

    // see above code for getPeople implementation...
    NSArray* existingPeopleArray = [self getPeople:idsToFetch];
    for (Person* p in existingPeopleArray)
    {
        [existingPeople setObject:p forKey:p.externalId];
    }

    for (NSDictionary* personDictionary in people)
    {
        NSString* externalId = [personDictionary objectForKey:@"PersonId"];
        Person* person = [existingPeople objectForKey:externalId];

        if (person == nil)
        {
            // the person was not in the context, make a new person in the context
            person = [[self newPerson] autorelease];
            person.ancestryId = externalId;
            [existingPeople setObject:person forKey:person.externalId];
        }

        // use JSON kit to populate the core data object...
        [PersonJSON populatePerson:person withDictionary:personDictionary inContext:[self context]];

        // these are just objects that contain an externalId, showing that the link hasn't been setup yet
        for (UnresolvedOtherPerson* other in person.unresolvedOtherPeople)
        {
            Person* relatedPerson = [existingPeople objectForKey:other.externalId];

            if (relatedPerson == nil)
            {
                relatedPerson = [[self newPerson] autorelease];
                relatedPerson.externalId = other.externalId;
                [existingPeople setObject:relatedPerson forKey:relatedPerson.externalId];
            }

            // add link - if I comment out this line, everything runs very fast
            // if I don't comment out, things slow down gradually and then exponentially
            [person addOtherPersonsObject:relatedPerson];
        }

        self.downloaded++;
    }

    [pool drain];
}
```

Comment: Instruments has a Core Data instrument that can be run in the iOS Simulator. I recommend you use that to trace what CoreData is doing.

Comment: Do you have two entities i.e. a `Person` entity and a `People` entity or just one entity `Person` that has a to-many relationship to other `Person` entities?

Comment: The code where you set the `otherPeople` relationship, the code you comment out, might be helpful.

Comment: It is a many to many relationship. The code just loops through an array of data structures, creates new Person objects and calls addOtherPeopleObject to add them.

Comment: Please answer TechZen's questions: One or two different entities? Code?

Comment: One entity, I am adding code now...

Comment: @KevinBallard Will definitely try the core data instruments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a result of inverse relationships. We had a parent object that could contain tens of thousands of child objects. By removing the inverse relationship between parent and child and maintaining it manually, performance is now constant!

Answer (score 3):

adding object to relationship causes the relationship on both side to fire. So if you have A <<->> B and say you are trying to add a freshly created A object to a B object that already has relationship with 100,000 A objects, CoreData will fetch that 100,000 objects from the store to fulfill the relationship before adding a new relationship.

The fact that you are clearing the mangedobjectcontext every so often means that all 100,000 objects CD loaded to fulfill the relationship now needs to be reloaded all over again, making the process extremely slow.

One way to work around this problem is by doing a two-step import process. First get all the objects loaded into db without establishing any relationships, but do keep track of which relationship needs to be added. Once you do a fast import like this, then go back to the db and add the relationships and clear context in such a way to avoid core-data having to reload the relationships too often. So as a concrete example, if you need to import 1 million `A`'s that needs to be associated with 100 `B`'s, first import all the `A`s, then for each of the hundred Bs, load the relationship once and add all the As to it, clear the context, move on to the next B, and so on. The key here is to prevent the context from reseting those 100k records that it just painfully loaded.

Another way to work around is to instead of resetting the whole context at regular intervals, only refresh the objects you want to get rid of.

Oh, one more thing, you could also consider having one-way relationship in CoreData, and use an explicit fetch to get the other side of the relationship

**EDIT**:

I think I found a workaround. You need to call the primitive accessors. so something like

```
        [self.primitiveTags addObject:tag];
```

Preliminary tests seems to show that this does not force the other side of the relationship to fire

Comment: If that is true that seems like terrible design. All I want to do is add a new relationship, I don't care about any of the existing relationships... yuck...

Comment: Terrible from a database perspective perhaps, but coredata is an object graph manager and thus must maintain integrity in the object graph. I got bitten by this and had to debug the underlying SQL query to figure this out.

Comment: I do think the firing of the fault on the inverse side of the relationship could be delayed until later though.

Comment: I don't suppose you know of a way to tell it not to load all the other relationships? :)

Comment: Lol if you figure out a way to do that, let me know as I am trying to find how to do it as well. That said, I edited the answer to post a potential workaround.

Comment: Cool, by one way relationship do you mean a relationship with no inverse?

Comment: Sadly too the relationships are pretty evenly distributed meaning all the A's are inter-related to all the other A's in a fairly random fashion.

Comment: yea, relationship with no inverse. tho it's not a  pretty road. Try manually refreshing objects instead of resetting the whole context tho, that could provide just what u needed